# How to execute pyinstaller exe on MacOs on click

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller to generate an executable using the command:

`sudo pyinstaller --onefile --windowed  myapp.py`

which generates an executable and a MacOs App. The issue is I want the terminal to open for the user to use the script. When I click on the app, the app opens an closes; which from what I've gathered is expected if it's not using a GUI. But the exe when I click on it just opens a terminal instead of running the script. If I open a terminal and use a command like

`./myapp`

then the application correctly executes. What should I do to remove the process of having to open a terminal?

Comment: You may also be interested to read through this known pyinstaller issue: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1804

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, the `--windowed` option has the opposite functionality that you desire:

> -w, --windowed, --noconsole
>
> Windows and Mac OS X: do not provide a console window for standard i/o. On Mac OS X this also triggers building an OS X .app bundle. This option is ignored in *NIX systems.

See the description of the options [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html). Could you try removing this option and running pyinstaller again?